# Is there any policy on dealing with serial homework questions?

Tags: discussion, homework

In the past few days, there have been four questions (at least) asking about the Dutch National Flag Problem, all from different users, with different levels of completion. From the code given in the questions, it is clear that all four are doing/asking about the same assignment question given by the same professor and by the tone, that they are due tomorrow :)

Is there any specific way to deal with these questions ? Closing them as duplicates of the first ? Flagging for group deletion as all of them are noise (they barely show an attempt) ?

[First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258047/dutch-national-flag-swap), [Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318198/worst-case-complexity-of-this-code-in-c), [Third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317965/worst-case-complexity-of-code-in-c), [Fourth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324382/dutch-national-flag)

Comment: Hum, there's [_another_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324604/file-not-being-created) iteration of that Dutch National Flag assignment...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd treat them as I would any other question.

- If it's a unique and on-topic question about some specific aspect of the same problem, go ahead and answer it (or leave it open for others to answer).
- If it's just a copy/paste of the homework question with no effort shown on the part of the student, close as 'not a real question'.
- If it's an exact duplicate of an earlier question, close it as a duplicate.  (And maybe leave a comment telling them they can get help from a classmate.)

Comment: Why not group deletion (if they happen to be poor questions) ? Seeing the same thing over and over is very irritating :/ (There were two more questions asking about the assignment IIRC, which were removed voluntarily)

Comment: @AshRj Why would this be any different than for non-homework questions? Just apply the regular rules and close accordingly, if appropriate. And if they serve no further purpose (no great answers, not a brilliant signpost to another dupe) then vote to delete if you can.