# How is this a failed reopen audit?

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits, vote-to-reopen

I failed a reopen audit. To be specific, reopen queue [#2326624](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/2326624). The question appears to have been closed as "Too Localized". That may not have been the right reason to close it, but I still shouldn't fail because of that.

Comment: How's "evidence of attempting to solve the problem himself" relevant? The lack of prior research is a reason to downvote a question, not close it.

Comment: @Yannis my mistake. reworded.

Comment: @Yannis In the OP's defense, questions that just paste a homework/quiz question from another source, tend to get closed as NARQ on SO. This is a [general policy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171195/200868).

Comment: I don't understand you rollback. You could just edit the link text instead of rollback.

Comment: @hims056 Because "To be specific, reopen queue" doesn't sound right. It's also bad practice to say "To be specific, this one".

Answer (score 1):

> That may not have been the right reason to close it, but I still shouldn't fail because of that.

Well then. You agree the reason stated for why it was closed was incorrect... And haven't volunteered any *other* reason why it should've been closed... So...

You don't think you should fail an audit for failing to re-open a question that shouldn't have been closed, while reviewing posts in the queue that exists for the express purpose of re-opening questions that shouldn't have been closed?

I suggest you do not use this queue then.

Comment: Did you not read @AsheeshR's comment above? It is NARQ. It's [policy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171195/200868)

Comment: Seems like a bit of a stretch, @Cole - I've seen a lot of copy-pasted homework questions, and while this could certainly have been derived from such a thing it doesn't read like a *verbatim copy* to me. FWIW, we're currently discussing more strict (and explicit) rules for this sort of thing here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185142/what-should-the-predefined-off-topic-reasons-be-for-stack-overflow - feel free to chime in.