# Audits that are incorrect

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I just failed an audit for attempting to close a duplicate question.

The audit was for the question: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2393046

I was going to mark it as a duplicate as I was sure the use of 'new' in Java must have come up before. Lo and behold I found this: [What does the 'new' keyword actually do in Java, and should I avoid creating new objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019754/what-does-the-new-keyword-actually-do-in-java-and-should-i-avoid-creating-new)

I feel that if you are going to audit close votes on questions then the questions should at least be unique. I realise this is a difficult task - but telling long standing members they have failed an audit when they have been very diligent is a bit off putting...

Comment: The audit system certainly isn't perfect, but the harshness of giving subjective tests punishments seems pretty off. Maybe a "No really, this needs closing, remove it from the audit queue in its current state" button could help.

Comment: For the record, the audit question's not a dupe of the other question you posted. The audit question is asking about a particular use of the `new` keyword in the context of nested class instantiation, while your other question is about the use of `new` in general.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184675/how-is-this-a-failed-reopen-audit

Comment: @Mac - that is a rather silly interpretation. They are both asking about the general use of the 'new' keyword. The audit question clearly states "What advantages does one get in declaring something like above and what are the alternatives to such declaration." - "Any advice/references would be greatly appreciated." - it couldn't be more general. I would still contend that it is a duplicate and that telling long standing members 'you have failed' is exactly the way to loose users.

Comment: @Fraser, look at it this way. Do you see any mention of "nested class" in the answers for the general question? Or, if you know how to use `new` in *general*, does that mean you'll know about nested classes?

Comment: @Fraser: with respect, I disagree. The audit question is quite specifically about not understanding the syntax of `new` in the precise context of inner class instantiation, which is quite a different thing to asking how the `new` operator works in the general case.

Comment: @doubleDown - An answer about the 'new' keyword in general should cover its uses. Just because the answers for the general question are incomplete doesn't mean that the questions don't match. If one question was "what does the + operator do" and one was "what does x + Y mean" I would say they are the same question - one specific and one general. The fact that the second might receive different or less complete answers to the first is irrelevant.

Comment: @Fraser: your example doesn't really match the situation. It's more like "why must I use `add()` instead of `+` to add two `Integer`s?", compared to "how does the + operator work?". Sure, they've got something in common, but that doesn't make them the same question.

Comment: @Mac - I guess we will have to agree to disagree. I still contend that "what does this specific use of new do" is covered by "what does new do in this language". In any case, my main point was that the audits should be unambiguous to avoid people wasting their time checking only to be told they have failed. Personally I will just avoid reviewing from now on as I came to help as far as I can - not to pass or fail some ambiguous test.